# Cloudfront conditional expiry

Tags: aws-lambda-edge, amazon-cloudfront

Can Lambda@Edge be used to expire the Cloudfront cache and force the fetch of a fresh version of a webpage?

I know that for the static assets something an additional query string can be added to avoid the cached version but now I'm asking for actual pages such as a site's homepage where that option is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront gives the option to invalidate the cache via the create-invalidation api.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html